# Удалить нулевые строки сверху и снизу numpy-матрицы

Tags: python, numpy

Есть ли какой-то не костыльный способ удалить нулевые строки сверху и снизу numpy-матрицы?
Пример

Input: `[[0, 0], [0, 0], [1, 2], [3, 4], [0, 0], [0, 0]]`

Output: `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то такое получилось:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 0], [1, 2], [3, 4], [0, 0], [0,0]])
cond = np.nonzero(~(arr == 0).all(axis=1))[0]
arr = arr[cond[0]:cond[-1]+1]
print(arr)
```

Вывод:

```
[[1 2]
 [3 4]]
```

**Update**: Или даже вот так что ли работает. Я не совсем понимаю логику работы `np.nonzero`, но, видимо, достаточно одной этой функции собственно:

```py
cond = np.nonzero(arr)[0]
arr = arr[cond[0]:cond[-1]+1]
```

Comment: а если будет `[0, 0], [1, 2],[0, 0] [3, 4]` ?

Comment: @splash58 Хороший вопрос. Но непонятно возможен ли такой вариант у автора вопроса.

Comment: ждем нового вопроса, когда реальные данные подкатят :)